# A-frame Want click on entity shows other entity

Tags: aframe

I have an entity and I want when I click or point with the a-frame cursor that is changes the attribute visible of another entity to true.

```
<a-entity id="pug" gltf-model="#pug" position="-1.75 0.0035 3" 
 scale="0.01 0.01 0.01" rotation="0 -11 0" >shadow
    event-set__down="_event: mousedown; scale: 1.2 1.2 1.2"
    event-set__up="_event: mouseup; scale: 1 1 1"
    event-set__leave="_event: mouseleave; scale: 1 1 1">
</a-entity>
```

If I have that the interaction with the cursor works but I don't how (or even if) I can make it affect the attribute of another entity.

I want that :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#pug").mouseenter(function(){
          $('#bubble').attr('visible', 'true');
        });
    });
</script>
```

I do have cursor in my camera but I don't know... I'm new to A-Frame and I must be missing something :/ Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind, that changing CSS properties won't affect the rendered entities. The best way to change properties is by using `entity.setAttribute("attribute", "value")`

---

I'm not sure if you can do a switch (visible / invisible) using the event-set component, but you can make an entity visible, or invisible by setting the visible attribute:

```
<a-entity event-set__click="_target: a-cylinder; visible: false;"></a-entity>
```

check it out [here](https://jsfiddle.net/a6ncrkm1/9/).

---

But i would recommend creating an a-frame component. You can check them out in the [docs](https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/core/component.html#sidebar), in this case it looks like this:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent("foo", {
  init: function() {
   this.el.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    let cylinder = document.querySelector("a-cylinder")
    cylinder.setAttribute("visible", !cylinder.getAttribute("visible"))
   })
  }
})
```

HTML:

```
<a-entity foo>
```

quite simple:
1) The `AFRAME.registerComponent("foo"` bit "declares" the component. 
2) The `init: function()` function is executed when the component is initialized 
3) Inside the click listener, I've made a simple toggle, which sets the visibility to the opposite of the actual value. If its visible, switch it to !visible = false.

Check it out [here](https://jsfiddle.net/a6ncrkm1/17/).

Comment: Hi Piotr, thanks for this example - would you mind explaining this line and how it acts as a toggle `!cylinder.getAttribute("visible")` ?

Comment: @Nick i've made an update, let me know if its more understandable now, btw thanks for the feedback :)

Comment: Thanks very much Piotr, that is helpful, its good for me to see that working because I normally write an if statement but that is much neater